# Reason for - ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified

Tags: sql, sql-server

I know that the query below causes the error - ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.

```
SELECT DISTINCT city
FROM HR.Employees
WHERE country = N'USA' AND region = N'WA'
ORDER BY birthdate;
```

What is the reason for this ? What is actually happening ? If I don't use DISTINCT or just add birthdate in SELECT or ORDER BY city only, it gives me some output, but not an error. Is it because `SELECT DISTINCT city` only gives a result set with cities and nothing else ?

**EDIT -(I think this may be an answer to my question)**

```
SELECT city
FROM HR.Employees
WHERE country = N'USA' AND region = N'WA'
```

Consider the above query. Not sure, but I think this is how it works - Behind the scenes, SQL Server probably has a result set with all columns, but we are only shown the city column which I will call the "displayed set" . So, ordering by city or any other column is valid.

What happens to the result set when we use SELECT DISTINCT city instead ? SQL server does not have only the rows with DISTINCT cities in its result set. It has the entire result set, like the one generated by a SELECT * query. But, it shows only distinct rows based on city. Now can this displayed set be sorted based on birthdate ? No.

In a city with many employees, ie many birthdates, SQL server cannot tell which birthdate should be used for ordering the displayed set. That is why it displays an error message.

Comment: I saw Joel Coehoorn's answer, but I am not sure if that is the best way to think about it - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/265628/order-by-items-must-appear-in-the-select-list-if-select-distinct-is-specified?rq=1

Comment: There can be multiple employees in a city so what birth date should it use when ordering the city?

Comment: @MartinSmith - I agree. My only doubt was if DISTINCT generates a result set which only has rows with distinct cities. I think that was the error in my thinking. So, I made an edit to my question. Please see it and tell me if it makes sense.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

A query with `SELECT DISTINCT` can be rewritten using `GROUP BY`. So the query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT city
FROM HR.Employees
WHERE country = N'USA' AND region = N'WA' ;
```

is equivalent to:

```
SELECT city
FROM HR.Employees
WHERE country = N'USA' AND region = N'WA'
GROUP BY city ;
```

and you can't use `ORDER BY birthdate` here either. The reason is the same for both queries. There may be many (more than one) rows with same `city` but different `birthdate`. Which one should be used for the ordering (if it was allowed?)

You can however use aggregate functions with a `GROUP BY` query:

```
SELECT city
FROM HR.Employees
WHERE country = N'USA' AND region = N'WA'
GROUP BY city 
ORDER BY MIN(birthdate) ;               -- or MAX(birthdate)
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you also see my update and tell me if it makes sense. I'd like to know if my guesswork makes sense.

Comment: Yes, I agree with those. Except for the last line ("In a city with many employees,...") Even if all cities have only one employee, the query would not be allowed. Because potentially, new employees can be inserted, i.e. SQL-Server does not examine the actual data but the query structure and enforced/declared constraints (and in this case, not even those).

Answer (score 1):

```
try this: 
select city 
    from (
    SELECT city, min(birthdate) as birthdate
    FROM HR.Employees
    WHERE country = N'USA' AND region = N'WA'
    group by city
          ) as t
    order by birthdate
```

Comment: I was not looking for a workaround or alternative code, but for an explanation of how things work.