# How to add Order by Clause in Stuff for XML Path Other than Columns in select Statement in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to perform a row concatenation Operation in SQL Server, for those rows which all have the same Master_ID. Also, the resulted output order is based on the `Seq_No Column`.

As I am using an older version of SQL Server, I am unable to use `STRING_AGG()` function.

As of now, I am using `Stuff and XML PATH` functions to achieve the row concatenation, but I am unable to order the resulted data based on the `Seq_No Column`.

Table script:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (Master_ID INT,
Associated_ID INT,
Class_ID INT,
Code VARCHAR(20),SEQ_No INT)


Insert into @T VALUES(1297232,NULL,3619202, '1101'  ,1)
Insert into @T VALUES(1297232,NULL,3619202, '0813'  ,2)
Insert into @T VALUES(1297232,NULL,3619202, '170219'    ,3)
Insert into @T VALUES(1297232,NULL,3619202, '19053299',1)
Insert into @T VALUES(1297232,1297233,3619202,'1101'    ,1)
Insert into @T VALUES(1297232,1297233,3619202,'0813'    ,2)
Insert into @T VALUES(1297232,1297233,3619202,'170219'  ,3)
Insert into @T VALUES(1297232,1297233,3619202,'19053299'    ,1)
Insert into @T VALUES(1297232,1297234,3619202,'1101'    ,1)
Insert into @T VALUES(1297232,1297234,3619202,'0813'    ,2)
Insert into @T VALUES(1297232,1297234,3619202,'170219'  ,3)
Insert into @T VALUES(1297232,1297234,3619202,'19053299'    ,1)
Insert into @T VALUES(1297232,1297235,3619202,'1101'    ,1)
Insert into @T VALUES(1297232,1297235,3619202,'0813'    ,2)
Insert into @T VALUES(1297232,1297235,3619202,'170219'  ,3)
Insert into @T VALUES(1297232,1297235,3619202,'19053299'    ,1)

SELECT * FROM @T
```

The query I tried with error:

```
SELECT STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT' ,'+Code
FROM @T
ORDER by ISNULL(Associated_ID,Master_ID),SEQ_No -- Reason for Error
FOR XML PATH (''),TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '')
```

Output for the above code:

```
0813 ,1101 ,170219 ,19053299
```

Expected output:

```
1101,19053299,0813,170219
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can swap `DISTINCT` for `GROUP BY` as they to the same and then you can order by aggregation functions like `SUM` or `MAX`

Example:

```
SELECT STUFF((SELECT ' ,'+Code
FROM @T
GROUP BY Code
ORDER by SUM(ISNULL(Associated_ID,Master_ID)),SUM(SEQ_No)
FOR XML PATH (''),TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '') 

-- OUTPUT: 1101 ,19053299 ,0813 ,170219
```

The error

> ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.

has nothing to do with the stuff, but the fact you are trying to sort on a distinct. [More info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18585057/639829)

Comment: Just want to say this saved my butt.  Thanks!