# SELECT DISTINCT with ORDER BY and CASE WHEN

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by, distinct

My query is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT LanguageCode
       FROM myTable
       ORDER BY (CASE WHEN LanguageCode='GB' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END), LanguageCode
```

The goal is to get languages, but to get GB language first.
And I'm getting this error:

```
ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.
```

I have seen the answers to this question:
[Reason for - ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18584520/reason-for-order-by-items-must-appear-in-the-select-list-if-select-distinct-is)

But I still don't understand why it applies to me (and how to solve it) as I'm only accessing a single column.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: That's obviously a bug. `LanguageCode` does appear in the select list, so you should be able to order by this column and expressions based on it.

Answer (score 1):

Somehow a workaround solution found by a colleague:

```
SELECT DISTINCT (CASE WHEN LanguageCode='GB' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS IsGB, LanguageCode
   FROM myTable
   ORDER BY IsGB ASC, LanguageCode
```

Answer (score 0):

Use aggregation instead:

```
SELECT LanguageCode
FROM myTable
GROUP BY LanguageCode
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN LanguageCode = 'GB' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END), 
         LanguageCode
```

Some databases are finicky about non-aggregated expressions in the `ORDER BY`.  If that is the case here, then you can use:

```
SELECT LanguageCode
FROM myTable
GROUP BY LanguageCode
ORDER BY MAX(CASE WHEN LanguageCode = 'GB' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END), 
         LanguageCode
```

Comment: Still the same error on my side :/
(I added one parenthesis you were missing for MAX)

Comment: @JBHurteaux . .  The `GROUP BY` query *cannot* generate an error about a `SELECT DISTINCT`.  That construct is not used in the query.