# Understanding of difference between MariaDB and SQL Server for a query

Tags: sql, mariadb-10.5

I am using MS SQL Server Version 2008 and MariaDB 10.5.

My table and data :

[image]

Following is the query i am running on both the databases.

```
 select distinct distributor from market order by city
```

Found this query is failing in MS SQL Server database with error

SQL Error [145] [S0001]: ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.
Understood the reason why it failing
[Reason for - ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18584520/reason-for-order-by-items-must-appear-in-the-select-list-if-select-distinct-is)

when i ran the same query run with MariaDB it ran successful without any error and gave me below output.

[image]

So i have doubt why MariaDB is behave different here? ideally it should fail right?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this query

Select distinct col from (
Select col from table order by col
)