# Comma separated for multiple items not working properly for SQL Sever 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I am using SQL Server 2012 (v11.0.5058.0 - X64). I want to perform comma separated for multiple columns. Since my SQL Server version is 2012 I can't use  `string_agg` or `ListAgg` so I am trying with a CTE and `FOR XML PATH` which is new for me.

**Output Explanation:**

Supposed If One `staff ID` Contain multiple `Cost_Center` then it should comma separated for respective `Staff_ID`

Current table:

```
Staff_No |  Name  | CostCenter     |  status  |
---------+--------+----------------+----------+
1270     | WASI   | 850110 - CPP   |   Active |
1345     | FAK    | 124600 - CPP   |   Active |
1270     | WASI   | 850870 - BKR   |   Active |
```

Desired output:

```
Staff_No |  Name  | CostCenter                   |  status  |
---------+--------+------------------------------+----------+
1270     | WASI   | 850110 - CPP , 850870 - BKR  |   Active |
1345     | FAK    | 124600 - CPP                 |   Active |
```

I tried this code:

```
WITH CTE_TableName AS 
(
    SELECT   
        a.Staff_No, a.Name,  
        CONVERT(varchar(19), a.COST_CENTER_CODE) + ' - ' + b.COST_CENTER_DESC  as CostCenter,   
        CASE a.Active 
           WHEN 1 THEN 'Active' 
           WHEN 2 THEN 'Inactive' 
        END AS status   
   FROM
       [FAV_VS_STAFF_M] a, [FAV_VS_COST_CENTER_M] b 
)
SELECT 
    t0.Staff_No, t0.Name, t0.status,
    STUFF((SELECT ',' + t2.CostCenter
           FROM CTE_TableName t2
           WHERE t2.Staff_No = t0.Staff_No
           ORDER BY t2.CostCenter
           FOR XML PATH('')), 1, LEN(','), '') AS FieldBs
FROM 
    CTE_TableName t0
GROUP BY 
    t0.Staff_No , t0.Name, t0.status
ORDER BY 
    Staff_No;
```

I am not getting the desired output. Where I am going wrong? Please help me

Comment: So what isn't working about what you have?

Comment: @Larnu I am getting all `Cost_Center` Data with comma separated but i need only those data which are multiple

Comment: Do you need `DISTINCT` in your inner query maybe?

Comment: @Charlieface I used but i am getting `ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.` error

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**almost 30 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: And also: **Bad habits to kick** - [using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Comment: Either use `ORDER BY 1` to order by the first (and only) column, or repeat the full `select` in the `ORDER BY`

Comment: I'm lost.  You show one table.  But your query references more than one table.  What does the data really look like?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Table  is just for sample output references should i post original table here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a rule, a `WHERE` clause of `SELECT .. FOR XML ..` shoud make the subquery depend on exactly the same columns which are listed in the `GROUP BY` clause of the outer query. Try

```
WITH CTE_TableName AS (
        SELECT   a.Staff_No , a.Name , 
        CONVERT(varchar(19), a.COST_CENTER_CODE) + ' - ' + b.COST_CENTER_DESC  as CostCenter,   
CASE a.Active WHEN 1 THEN 'Active' WHEN 2 THEN 'Inactive' END AS status   
from [FAV_VS_STAFF_M] a, [FAV_VS_COST_CENTER_M] b )
SELECT t0.Staff_No, t0.Name , t0.status
     , STUFF((
       SELECT ',' + t2.CostCenter
         FROM CTE_TableName t2
        WHERE t2.Staff_No = t0.Staff_No
            AND t2.Name = t0.Name AND t2.status = t0.status
        ORDER BY t2.CostCenter
          FOR XML PATH('')), 1, LEN(','), '') AS FieldBs
  FROM CTE_TableName t0
  GROUP BY t0.Staff_No , t0.Name, t0.status
  ORDER BY Staff_No;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=8ceaf04f0cef6894933d04985d899cf9)

Comment: As i am getting all multiple `Cost_Center` i am looking if `Staff_ID` as multiple `Cost_Center` then it should separated with comma. Kindly Check My updated question

Comment: Added db<>fiddle .

Answer (score 0):

**You need a `DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY` clause in your inner `SELECT` if you only want distinct values.** There are a number of ways to do this, the simplest is:

```sql
    STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + t2.CostCenter
           FROM CTE_TableName t2
           WHERE t2.Staff_No = t0.Staff_No
             AND t2.Name = t0.Name AND t2.status = t0.status
           ORDER BY 1
           FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)')
    , 1, LEN(','), '') AS FieldBs
```

**Note the addition of `TYPE` and `value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)')` to ensure the XML is unescaped properly.**

As noted by @Serg, you also need to correlate the join properly `AND t2.Name = t0.Name AND t2.status = t0.status`

Another way to skin this cat:

```sql
    STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + t2.CostCenter
           FROM CTE_TableName t2
           WHERE t2.Staff_No = t0.Staff_No
             AND t2.Name = t0.Name AND t2.status = t0.status
           ORDER BY ',' + t2.CostCenter
           FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)')
    , 1, LEN(','), '') AS FieldBs
```

Or:

```sql
    STUFF((SELECT ',' + t2.CostCenter
           FROM CTE_TableName t2
           WHERE t2.Staff_No = t0.Staff_No
             AND t2.Name = t0.Name AND t2.status = t0.status
           GROUP BY ',' + t2.CostCenter
           ORDER BY ',' + t2.CostCenter
           FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)')
    , 1, LEN(','), '') AS FieldBs
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265628/order-by-items-must-appear-in-the-select-list-if-select-distinct-is-specified) for why you need to specify the `ORDER BY` like this.

Comment: I tried as you suggested but i am getting error like `Cannot call methods on nvarchar(max).`

Comment: Same Output i am getting its showing all `Cost_Center` data

Comment: I tried all three ways but same output i am getting repeating for all `Cost_Center` .

Comment: Serg is right you need to correlate the apply. have modified

Comment: i used Serg Query but same result i am getting